# Map Keys -Mutable or Non-Mutable

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

Which is better in terms of hashing/performance as a key for a Map a mutable or non-mutable

And why so?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Don't use mutable objects, period, if the object's `hashCode()`/`equals()` can change. It'll then be in the wrong place, and the `Map` will probably lose track of it.

Answer (score 1):

Mutability has no effect on the performance, only the implementation of hashCode and equals method could influence the performance since hashing uses only these methods.

As chriylis already pointed out you shouldn't modify key-objects already placed in a Map thats because the hash value changes and Map.get can no longer find them.

Answer (score 0):

These are not connected. You would need to reinsert an object into map if you modify it (remove - modify - insert). If you modify a key without removal, you won't be able to reference it - i.e. to remove or get it the normal way.